# how to get TimeZoneInfo short name

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime, date

Is there any method to get the 3 char code from 
System.TimeZoneInfo.Local
?

e.g. EDT instead of Eastern Daylight time etc.

Comment: It should be noted that one can not merely determine the daylight or not from just a timezone info.  For instance, looking at the registry as suggested, one can see all the names only include "Standard" and not "Daylight".  Therefore you won't have an accurate answer (that takes into account Daylight) without involving a DateTime somewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy built-in way of doing this that I know of. However, you could put something together yourself. Here's an example:

```
public static class TimeZoneInfoExtensions {

        public static string Abbreviation(this TimeZoneInfo Source) {

        var Map = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"eastern standard time","est"},
            {"mountain standard time","mst"},
            {"central standard time","cst"},
            {"pacific standard time","pst"}
            //etc...
        };

        return Map[Source.Id.ToLower()].ToUpper();

    }

}
```

Use as follows:

```
string CurrentTimeZoneAbbreviation = System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.Abbreviation();
```

If you need more conversions you could just plug them into the Map dictionary.

TimeZoneInfo.Id will be a string matching a given key in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones]. If you can find a matching database online, containing the same Ids as well as the abbreviations, it would be possible to quickly extract and import the pairs (with regular expressions, for example) and drop those into the Map dictionary.

Comment: The possible values for `Id` can be found in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zone` (they're different from the names in http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/ )

Answer (score 4):

You can write something like:

```
var abbr = System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.TimeZoneAbbr();
```

And the helper for it:

```
public static class ConvertionHelper
{
    public static String TimeZoneAbbr(this TimeZoneInfo zone)
    {
        var zoneName = zone.Id;/* zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.UtcNow)
            ? zone.DaylightName
            : zone.StandardName;*/
        var zoneAbbr = zoneName.CapitalLetters();
        return zoneAbbr;
    }

    public static String CapitalLetters(this String str)
    {
        return str.Transform(c => Char.IsUpper(c)
            ? c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            : null);
    }

    private static String Transform(this String src, Func<Char, String> transformation)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src))
        {
            return src;
        }

        var result = src.Select(transformation)
            .Where(res => res != null)
            .ToList();

        return String.Join("", result);
    }
}
```