# Is it possible to convert short time zone strings as EST CET PST to TimeZoneInfo in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, time, timezone

The short time zone string I'm getting it as input. I'm trying to avoid to hardcode myself a huge mapping.

Comment: ~Can you give an example of the type of "short" value you're expecting?~ Sorry, I just saw that's in the title.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862335/convert-local-time-zone-to-pst-time-zone-in-c-sharp It looks like a solution that you want

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that will not work for me. The string time zone is not known and not limited to a subset. So, I can not hardcode the translation from short time zone string to long time zone string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get TimeZoneInfo short name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402544/how-to-get-timezoneinfo-short-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it. Because for some abbreviations we have several full names:
"AMT" means UTC+4 (Armenia Time) also "AMT" means UTC-4 (Amazon Time). That's why Microsoft didn't add this in his `TimeZoneInfo` class. I think it's much better to talk with the customer and decide which dictionary you will use.

You can find the list of abbreviations here: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/

Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's a built-in way of doing it. You might find the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402544/how-to-get-timezoneinfo-short-name) to be the simplest solution